# Add Custom Web Part to newly created page programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, feature-activation, solution-deployment, project-server

I created a custom web part for SharePoint 2013 and I would like it to be added to a blank page that is created for it.

I looked it up and found out, that the I can add an Event Receiver to the Feature, so I added one, but the event receiver is never fired.

The event that I tried was the ***FeatureActivated*** and ***FeatureInstalled***.

Do I have to set some kind of special properties for the project to make the event handlers work?

Is there any other way to create a blank sharepoint web page and add a custom web part to it programmatically?

I used this tutorial : [Create a Web part page with web part](http://sharepointwithravi.blogspot.dk/2011/04/create-web-part-page-with-web-part-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy it with module, follow below article 
https://amalhashim.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/sharepoint-deploy-webpart-page-using-module/

As well you can create feature in your solution,and on the activation of the feature you can add the webpart to the page

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
    using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        using(SPLimitedWebPartManager wpManager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(page url, System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared))
        {
            YourWebPart webpart = new YourWebPart();
            webpart.ZoneID = "Top";
            webpart.Title = "My Webpart";
            wpManager.AddWebPart(webpart,"Top" , 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first one did not work, it just deployed the web part as it did the first time I ran it. No page created.

The second one, as I said in my first post, is not firing. The debugger is not getting into that point of the code neither.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer worked, with one minor adjustment

```
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
    using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        using(SPLimitedWebPartManager wpManager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(page url, System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared))
        {
            YourWebPart webpart = new YourWebPart();
            //webpart.Zone.ID = "Top";
            webpart.Title = "My Webpart";
            wpManager.AddWebPart(webpart,"Top" , 0);
        }
    }
}
```